# Azure function with event hub trigger and Streaming Analytics job working together?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-stream-analytics

I am trying to make some external api calls which takes a minute to finish up using a function when a message is received in IOThub builtin endpoint (eventhubtrigger).

However, there is also an azure streaming analytics job running to send data to cosmosdb after some filtering.

My question is, can both of them work together without any major latency (>1s) in sending data to cosmosdb ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes they can work together very well, when it comes to the latency it really depends on the consistency level that you choose with Cosmosdb. You can have a look at this [reference architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/example-scenario/data/fraud-detection) which includes the similar services.